# Unmake move vs copy board in chess programming

Tags: python, chess

I'm at the start of creating a chess engine. When I created a function that checks if a move is legal, first I had to make the move and then check if the move had put my king in check and then unmake it.

After giving some thought on how to make a function that unmakes a move, I decided it's much simpler to just copy the board and make the hypothetical move on the copied board, so it doesn't change the original board structure at all.

But I'm worried this might be a bad idea because when I get to the AI part, as I have to copy the board completely, and it might slow down my engine. Is it so? Could you please share your thoughts about this, since I don't know much about algorithm complexity and that kind of stuff.

Thank you.

Comment: you might want to check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern

Comment: @geekkid - It depends a lot on the size of your board structure and on how many field updates are needed to make and unmake a move. It is not all all certain which method is the fastest, so just use the one you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: take a look at http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Copy-Make

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say, copying the whole board is likely to slow things down quite a bit. I suggest making an undo list, to which you add the reverse of every move you make. Then to undo, simply repeatedly pop moves off the list and apply them until the list is empty. This way your AI can explore all the possibilities by using a simple recursive function with a maxdepth parameter.

**Re: Bo's Comment**

I respectfully disagree.

For programs written in lower-level languages a board copy may amount to a single memcpy, and then it might very well be faster. But for an object orientated python program, where there's one object per chess piece, plus metadata, a fully independent game state copy is almost certainly much slower than creating a single new "undo" object and adding it to a list.

Mind you, this has little to do with the size of the structure, and more with the number of operations required to copy that structure. Especially in python, function calls add a significant amount of overhead. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11722271/566644) answer (my own), instantiating 32 piece objects in CPython is equivalent to 83 function calls, and that is presuming they do not have any subclasses other than `object`. Then the data allocation and copying comes on top of that.

If the board had been a 16x16 numpy array, I agree a board copy might be faster.

Comment: It is not at all certain that copying the board is slower. It depends very much on the size of the board state structure. Using copy-discard makes the undo function extremely fast, which can save more than the cost of copying the board. Both methods are used in real chess programs.

Comment: I have never written a chess program in Python, but have done it in C++. There a copy *can* be faster, copy constructors and everything. The size of the structure goes against the available memory bandwidth, which is one limiting factor.

Comment: It depends on the architecture. Robert Hyatt, the author of Cray Blitz, which eventually became Crafty, first used copy/make because copying memory was extremely fast on a Cray. Later, he had to switch to make/unmake in Crafty when porting it to a PC, as it became a major bottleneck there (due to cache pollution). I think nowadays, most engines are using make/unmake. (I don't know about performance tuning in Python, though.)

Answer (score 5):

Generally the unmake approach is used more as it avoids unnecessary copying of the board.  This is especially true if you want to keep your pieces in two different forms in your `Position` class; as a traditional 8x8 array and as a set of 64-bit unsigned integers (bitboards).

You need to create a class to store your `UnmakeMoveInfo` which holds:

- The from/to of the move.
- The previous position hash.
- The 'halfmove clock'.
- The en-passant mask.
- The captured piece.
- The previous position flags (check, ep_move, castling rights).

So that you have all the info required to unmake the move.