# How many function calls does it take to create a class instance?

Tags: python

Knowing that calling a function in python is expensive, the answer to this question has some bearing on optimization decisions, e.g. in comparing a straight one-function numeric approach to an object-oriented one. So I'd like to know

- What's the typical number of function calls required?
- What's the minimum number of function calls required?
- What increases the number of calls?
- How does user-created classes compare to built-in classes?
- What about object deletion (including garbage collection)?

My google-fu was not up to the task of finding an answer to this question.

**EDIT:** So to summarize the comments and forestall more close votes, here's some clarifications:

- I'm interested in the time-complexity of python instance creation compared to calling a normal python function
- For the purposes of this question, let's limit ourselves to the newest CPython versions.

Comment: Do you mean how many instructions does it take for a Python class to be set up once invoked?

Comment: Which function calls do you want to count? Python function calls, or C function calls in the Python interpreter?

Comment: @Mark Well, this is where I hope the answers will do a bit of explanation, as I'm not sure of the "conversion factor" between python function calls, instructions and C function calls. The main point is I want some sort of measure of the time-complexity of a simple python function call vs. python object instantiation.

Comment: @close voters: I fail to see how this question is not fact-related or does not require expertise. It deals with exactly measurable things and it requres deep python internals knowledge to answer this question.

Comment: Why is this of interest? Better write nice, elegant and efficient code  instead of performing optimizations ages before you are in the stage of benchmarking your code.

Comment: @lazyr -- This might not be the answer that you're looking for, but why not set up some simple tests and time them via `timeit`?

Comment: @lazyr: it depends too much on the task at hand. I believe the *minimum* number of function calls is one (the constructor), but the *typical* number depends on what kind of class you're constructing. Similarly for the comparison to built-in classes, and for object deletion. You are indeed asking about measurable things, but "how to measure" would be a better question, IMHO.

Comment: @Maulwurfn Indeed, but I'm one of those guys who can't let a question go once it has entered my mind, even though I know it's of very little practical relevance

Comment: It might help if you specify a specific implementation - There's a slight problem in that Python is a language specification - not an implementation. CPython, Cython, Jython, IronPython, PyPy (or CPython with Psyco etc..), will have different optimisations depending on the underlying platform (CPython's, .NET, JVM, Hybrid, JIT, etc...) and different methods of garbage collection, threading, IO,  etc... Even different versions of the same implementation differ - eg, algorithms have changed - not to mention new/old style classes, __slots__, metaclasses, and, and, and...

Comment: @mgilson Yes, but as I said, I did not find an answer to this question on google, and that means it could use an answer on SO, to avoid duplication of effort. I'll probably do that if I get no answers, and answer myself.

Comment: @Jon Good points. I guess when I wrote this question I had new versions of CPython in mind, i.e. 2.7 or 3.2.

Comment: If you can formulate a specific question with an example, you may have some luck on http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev - the core developers are fairly friendly, albeit quiten often short of time :)

Comment: @Jon I'll not rob them of any then, and answer this question myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Python Object Creation](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/16/python-object-creation-sequence/) by Eli Bendersky.

Quoting at length the conclusion:

> Lest we lose the forest for the trees, let’s revisit the question this
>   article began with. What happens when CPython executes `j = Joe()`?
>
> - Since `Joe` has no explicit metaclass, `type` is its type. So the `tp_call` slot of `type`, which is `type_call`, is called.
> - `type_call` starts by calling the `tp_new` slot of Joe:
>
>   - Since Joe has no explicit base clase, its base is `object`. Therefore, `object_new` is called.
>   - Since Joe is a Python-defined class, it has no custom `tp_alloc` slot. Therefore, `object_new` calls `PyType_GenericAlloc`.
>   - `PyType_GenericAlloc` allocates and initializes a chunk of memory big enough to contain Joe.
> - `type_call` then goes on and calls `Joe.__init__` on the newly created object.
>
>   - Since `Joe` does not define `__init__`, its base’s `__init__` is called, which is `object_init`.
>   - `object_init` does nothing.
> - The new object is returned from `type_call` and is bound to the name `j`.

Comment: Thank you! That's a very interesting article.

Comment: @lazyr:  In this short quote the answers to four of your five questions can be inferred.

Comment: Bear in mind, the majority of these calls are C calls, so the OP's concern over the expense of function calls in Python does not necessarily apply.

Comment: @DanielRoseman:  Excellent point.  Do note, however that there are at least three places we customize this process in Python -- in `__init__`, in `__new__`, and in a metaclass that defines `__call__`.

Answer (score 3):

I've done as suggested in the comments and used `timeit` on these test cases:

```
def a():
    pass

class A(object):
    pass

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class NOPType(type):
    pass

class C(object):
    __metaclass__ = NOPType
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class D(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(D, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class E(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(E, self).__init__()
```

Test results:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "import tst" "tst.a()"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.149 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "import tst" "tst.A()"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.169 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "import tst" "tst.B()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.384 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "import tst" "tst.C()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.397 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "import tst" "tst.D()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "import tst" "tst.E()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.827 usec per loop
```

Using a function call as a baseline, these are the results:

- a basic instantiation takes 1.1 times more time.
- adding an `__init__` method increases the factor to 2.6
- adding a no-op metaclass is just a tiny bit more expensive, at 2.7
- instead adding a basic `__new__`, it's equivalent to 7.3 function calls
- a class with a single subclass is equivalent to 5.6 function calls

For the last two result you can subtract about 2 if the call to `super` is replaced with its return value.

This should give a rough estimate of how time-expensive python classes are compared to python functions, in CPython 2.7.

Comment: +1.  Presumably, your objects will have data.  If you are going to create a large number of objects, you may want to optimize memory usage by using `__slots__`.  I would suggest not using `__slots__`, but keeping it mind if you need the optimization.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the original question directly, but that's a good thing!

Comment: @hop I found out while answering comments that my question formulation did not match what I actually wanted to know. However, I've decided against updating the question, because then the comments would not make sense.